# MySQL ORDER BY columns across multiple joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing, sql-order-by

I have a database which consists of three tables, with the following structure:

**restaurant table:** restaurant_id, location_id, rating. **Example:** 1325, 77, 4.5

**restaurant_name table:** restaurant_id, language, name. **Example:** 1325, 'en', 'Pizza Express'

**location_name table:** location_id, language, name. **Example:** 77, 'en', 'New York'

I would like to get the restaurant info in English, sorted by location name and restaurant name, and use the LIMIT clause to paginate the result. So my SQL is:

```
SELECT ln.name, rn.name
FROM restaurant r
INNER JOIN location_name ln
ON r.location_id = ln.location_id
AND ln.language = 'en'
INNER JOIN restaurant_name rn
ON r.restaurant_id = rn.restaurant_id
AND rn.language = 'en'
ORDER BY ln.name, rn.name
LIMIT 0, 50
```

This is terribly slow - so I refined my SQL with deferred JOIN, which make things a lot faster (from over 10 seconds to 2 seconds):

```
SELECT ln.name, rn.name
FROM restaurant r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT r.restaurant_id
    FROM restaurant r
    INNER JOIN location_name ln
    ON r.location_id = ln.location_id
    AND ln.language = 'en'
    INNER JOIN restaurant_name rn
    ON r.restaurant_id = rn.restaurant_id
    AND rn.language = 'en'
    ORDER BY ln.name, rn.name
    LIMIT 0, 50
) r1
ON r.restaurant_id = r1.restaurant_id
INNER JOIN location_name ln
ON r.location_id = ln.location_id
AND ln.language = 'en'
INNER JOIN restaurant_name rn
ON r.restaurant_id = rn.restaurant_id
AND rn.language = 'en'
ORDER BY ln.name, rn.name
```

2 seconds is unfortunately still not very acceptable to the user, so I go and check the EXPLAIN of the my query, and it appears that the slow part is on the ORDER BY clause, which I see "Using temporary; Using filesort". I checked the official reference manual about [ORDER BY optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html#order-by-index-use) and I come across this statement:

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY,
>   although it may still use indexes to find the rows that match the
>   WHERE clause. Examples:
>
> The query joins many tables, and the columns in the ORDER BY are not
>   all from the first nonconstant table that is used to retrieve rows.
>   (This is the first table in the EXPLAIN output that does not have a
>   const join type.)

So for my case, given that the two columns I'm ordering by are from the nonconstant joined tables, index cannot be used. My question is, is there any other approach I can take to speed things up, or what I've done so far is already the best I can achieve?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT 1**

Below is the EXPLAIN output with the ORDER BY clause:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys            | key                   | key_len | ref                            | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                     | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                           |   50 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | rn         | ref    | idx_restaurant_name_1    | idx_restaurant_name_1 | 1538    | r1.restaurant_id,const,const   |    1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | r          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_restaurant_1 | PRIMARY               | 4       | r1.restaurant_id               |    1 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ln         | ref    | idx_location_name_1      | idx_location_name_1   | 1538    | test.r.location_id,const,const |    1 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | rn         | ALL    | idx_restaurant_name_1    | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                           | 8484 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | r          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_restaurant_1 | PRIMARY               | 4       | test.rn.restaurant_id          |    1 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ln         | ref    | idx_location_name_1      | idx_location_name_1   | 1538    | test.r.location_id             |    1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Below is the EXPLAIN output without the ORDER BY clause:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys            | key                   | key_len | ref                            | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                     | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                           |   50 |                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | rn         | ref    | idx_restaurant_name_1    | idx_restaurant_name_1 | 1538    | r1.restaurant_id,const,const   |    1 | Using where              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | r          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_restaurant_1 | PRIMARY               | 4       | r1.restaurant_id               |    1 |                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ln         | ref    | idx_location_name_1      | idx_location_name_1   | 1538    | test.r.location_id,const,const |    1 | Using where              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | rn         | index  | idx_restaurant_name_1    | idx_restaurant_name_1 | 1538    | NULL                           | 8484 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DERIVED     | r          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_restaurant_1 | PRIMARY               | 4       | test.rn.restaurant_id          |    1 |                          |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ln         | ref    | idx_location_name_1      | idx_location_name_1   | 1538    | test.r.location_id             |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

**EDIT 2**

Below are the DDL of the table. I built them for illustrating this problem only, the real table has much more columns.

```
CREATE TABLE restaurant (
  restaurant_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  location_id INT NOT NULL,
  rating INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (restaurant_id),
  INDEX idx_restaurant_1 (location_id)
);

CREATE TABLE restaurant_name (
  restaurant_id INT NOT NULL,
  language VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  INDEX idx_restaurant_name_1 (restaurant_id, language),
  INDEX idx_restaurant_name_2 (name)
);

CREATE TABLE location_name (
  location_id INT NOT NULL,
  language VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  INDEX idx_location_name_1 (location_id, language),
  INDEX idx_location_name_2 (name)
);
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes on your tables?  Even if there don't help the order by they will still speed up your queries.

Comment: @Jhorra Yes I do, on all the _id columns as well as the name column for both the location_name and restaurant_name table. The indices on the two name columns aren't helpful at all unfortunately, which is kinda expected as it is inline with what the manual says.

Comment: How does this query even execute?  You are doing INNER JOIN location_name ln ON r.location_id = ln.location_id 
but r.location_id isn't even a field available from the select statement that makes up the r dataset.

Comment: Are you able to share a count of the approximate number of records in each of your three tables?  Also, have you attempted to run the query removing the order by clauses from both the query and sub-query to see how fast it will run?

Comment: First of all, as @user681574 mentions, your query is wrong: the inner query does not contain enough fields to be used in subsequent joins. So probably this is not the exact approach you followed. Moreoever, the inner query does exactly what your original query does (apart from the limit which has been changed from 50 to 30), it just does not return two fields (restaurant_name, location_name) and you need to go back and ask the same tables again to fetch them. So how can this approach run a lot faster than the first, when it actually has to do even more joins?

Comment: @user681574 Yes the SQL I wrote had some problems when I simplified it for easy reading on SO. I've now gotten it corrected. The restaurant table has around 16k records, restaurant_name table has 64k, and location_name has 11k. The sub-query runs a lot faster without the ORDER BY clause, from 2 seconds down to 100ms.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis I've corrected the SQL, it was wrong earlier when I simplified it from the original query for easy reading on SO. And regarding to your question about the inner query - to be honest I wasn't convinced before for the exact same reason, but it actually helps. I learnt this deferred join method from point 2 of the below URL: http://www.iheavy.com/2013/06/19/3-ways-to-optimize-for-paging-in-mysql/

Comment: You will need an index `location_name(language, name)` (assuming `location_id` is your primary key) and `restaurant(location_id, name)`. Also, your deferred join should not be faster in this case (it can only be faster if your offset is > 0, and will usually not be faster if you use a join in the inner query), so at least try it without it, it might be just caching that made you think it is faster. Also please always add the `explain`-output (especially if these 2 indexes don't make it faster, then you might have to use a `straight_join`). It is a vital part in optimization questions.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks for your advice. I would like to clarify with you on the second index that you mentioned - restaurant(location_id, name). This table doesn't have a name column... And for the deferred join, the offset can be any number depends on which page user is navigating. But anyways the offending part seems to be the ORDER BY clause. I've  updated my question with the EXPLAIN output with and without the ORDER BY clause. It results in a filesort and is drastically slower... For a smaller data set, the execution time is 0.31s vs 0.01s.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I assumed the wrong column. Restaurants have different name in different languages? In that case you cannot prevent the filesort, because you simply have no table that contains the required data so that you can order an index for it. Especially with just 1.5 restaurants per location, you could think about just creating such a table, which basically means making `(locationid, someid)` your pk in `restaurant`. Currently, the first index should help a bit. `ln` should now be the first row in `explain` (without the deferred join, you should first optimize without that).

Comment: @Solarflare Yes I do have name in different languages, thus I created another table for translation purpose. May I know how do you derive the figure 1.5 restaurants per location? For my testing setup I have roughly 100 restaurants (it's randomly generated) per location actually, and for the production setup the max can go up to 6000 per location.

Comment: @Solarflare With regards to having another table for indexing - will the key (location_id, some_id) help sorting the name column? In fact for simplicity I didn't mention that there are a few sort options available for users to choose from. They can sort by location, by name, by rating, etc. I didn't mention earlier as I thought there might be a way to generically tackle the ORDER BY slowness.

Comment: Ordering over several tables is always tricky, depending on specific circumstances, not generically solvable and not even all combination are indexable at all. E.g. if you add `location_id` to `restaurant_name` and use `(location_id, restaurant_id)` as the primary key everywhere, you can tackle e.g. `order by ln.name, rn.name` in case `ln.name` is unique, but usually not `order by rn.name, ln.name` (because `rn.name` is probably not unique).

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; it is hard to read the `EXPLAINs` without them.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks for your help. I always wonder how does websites like TripAdvisor, or those hotel booking websites (hotels.com, Agoda, etc) works... As they do provide huge set of data per location, and they allow users to have their own sorting preference. I've never find them very slow.

Comment: They hire people who have the experience in the required areas to come up with ways to solve the problem in a way they need it. For one, they will choose a data model that fits their requirements (which would include fast search). You have the requirement to have the flexibility to store restaurant names for different languages. Your data model is fine for that. But, as it turns out, not for ordering by them. Without the name flexibility, your ordering would already be a lot faster (with e.g. the index/column I assumed in my first comment) even with this simple model.

Comment: @Solarflare I've studied a couple of sites. Most of them don't offer sorting by names actually, instead they allow sorting by popularity, rating, no. of comments etc which in my case can be easily incorporated as a numeric field in the restaurant table. TripAdvisor is quite powerful tho - it does offer alphabetical sort in English, and other logical sort options for other languages (say no. of strokes for Chinese). This is really impressive, unfortunately I really don't have a grip on how this can be achieved. Maybe it's about the limit of MySQL as a DBMS, or relational database in general?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `EXPLAIN` numbers, there could be about 170 "pages" of restaurants (8484/50)?  I suggest that that is impractical for paging through.  I strongly recommend you rethink the UI.  In doing so, the performance problem you state will probably vanish.

For example, the UI could be 2 steps instead of 170 to get to the restaurants in Zimbabwe. Step 1, pick a country.  (OK, that might be page 5 of the countries.)  Step 2, view the list of restaurants in that country; it would be only a few pages to flip through.  Much better for the user; much better for the database.

**Addenda**

In order to optimize the pagination, get the paginated list of pages from a *single* table (so that you can 'remember where you left off').  *Then* join the language table(s) to look up the translations.  Note that this only looks up on page's worth of translations, not thousands.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Rick. You are correct that there are many "pages", but I don't make them explicit. The listing is implemented as an infinite scroll, like Facebook feed. That's why I need a few different sorting order to ease user's browsing. With regards to the location filter it is already in place, but I'm still encountering this problem. There can be really a lot of restaurants in a country/city. My site frankly speaking isn't that popular, but still accumulated over 7k entries for one single location.

Comment: Ever see an encyclopedia set?  20 (or so) volumes, labeled  "A-At", "Au-Ce", "Ch-Cu", etc.  At a glance, you knew which volume to grab.  That's one way to deal with 170 "Next" clicks.  Another way is to refuse to do more than, say, 10 pages.  Instead force the user to give more specifics.  Such as the Rating.  Or the Postal Code.  Or break it into manageable chunks by latitude and longitude.  Or city areas (Uptime, Downtime, Lincoln Park, Homewood, Haight District, Financial District).

Comment: 7K items in an infinite scroll will keep your page "not that popular".  Let this be a learning exercise.  Experiment with some of the ideas I mentioned.  Throw them out and invent new ones.  Your journey can be an exciting adventure.

Comment: Well unless you are saying TripAdvisor is also "not that popular", otherwise I don't see what's actually wrong to have many pages? TripAdvisor shows 20 restaurants per page and it has 89 pages for Japan - https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g294232-oa1760-Japan.html#LOCATION_LIST. It provides two sorting options - by popularity and alphabetically.

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I'm not saying the design of TripAdvisor is the best out there, but I just wanna prove that it is doable. Back to my original question, I would like to know technically how this can be achieved. I'm assuming a context just for sake of illustration. If you take this as a pure database tuning question - I have several tables to join and I would like to sort on some columns from each of the joined tables. Is there a way to make this faster?

Comment: Does TripAdvisor use MySQL?  Does it have so much RAM that there is no need for I/O?  Is it using AJAX to get to the next chunk?  Have they arranged for the data to be in a single, simple, table?

Comment: I can make pagination very fast, regardless of number of pages.  But it probably requires change(s) to your schema.  See [_this_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

Comment: Frankly speaking I don't know the implementation of TripAdvisor (and I doubt if they disclose). As I've pointed out in another comment, I do also suspect it might be a limitation on MySQL as a DBMS or relational database in general. If I have to make a guess on the data schema of TripAdvisor, I don't think it will be simple. Given that the site is multilingual, I imagine they will have an attraction table for the basics and a translation table for different languages, if their database is relational. The interesting part is they provide a sort that can logically adapt to each language.

Comment: Thanks for the reference about pagination, I'll have a read and see if it can resolve my problem.

Comment: I had read your article in details. I've in fact come across this approach elsewhere before, but it doesn't resolve my problem unfortunately. The key takeaway is to use the same column in WHERE clause and ORDER BY clause, say WHERE id >= xyz ORDER BY id, and have the id column indexed. For my original problem, I'm referencing columns in the joined tables, which index won't help. Thus this approach cannot be taken. You may suggest to move those columns into the same table, but then I cannot handle names in multi-language. It is a dilemma for me.

Comment: @CLDev - and that's why I said it probably requires schema changes.  See my addenda.  Forget about languages for now; focus on optimizing the pagination.  Get only the ids of the items on the 'page'.  _Then_ use `JOINs` to get the rest of the data, including translations.

Comment: If you see my order by clause "ORDER BY ln.name, rn.name", I'm sorting the translated names alphabetically. How can I forget about languages for now? If I'm sorting by say number of visits or ratings, I do see your point.

Comment: You added languages to start with, then stumbled over performance in Pagination.  I am suggesting to do the tasks in the other order -- focus on pagination performance, then add in languages.